# Triggering a function when entering a route (react-router-dom)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <StyledMain>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Splash} render={()=>{alert('dd"')}}/>
        <Route path="/files" component={Files} />
        <Route path="/archived" component={Archived} />
        <Route path="/extract/:filename" component={Extract} />
        <Route path="/docs/api" component={Docs} />
      </Switch>
    </StyledMain>
  </div>
)
```

In my main.js, I tried to trigger an alert whenever I enter the main route `('/')`. However, this does not work.

I also tried `onEnter`, but realized that this is for the older version.

Is this the right usage?

Comment: The `render` prop is used for rendering something when the `path` of the `Route` matches the URL. Does it fit your use case to put the `alert` in the `Splash` component constructor?

Comment: I don't understand. "/" path redirects the user to Spalsh.

Comment: Yes, but you could put the logic inside the `Splash` component instead of calling it in the `render` prop.

Comment: What I eventually want to do is to put an authentication modal so that users cannot access the Route without authentication.

Comment: Then you can create and use a PrivateRoute and do the logic there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put alert in your Splash component as @Tholle suggested in the comment. But with `render` you can do this without using component:

```
const Main = () => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <StyledMain>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
                alert('dd"');
                return <Splash />;
            }
        }/>
        <Route path="/files" component={Files} />
        <Route path="/archived" component={Archived} />
        <Route path="/extract/:filename" component={Extract} />
        <Route path="/docs/api" component={Docs} />
      </Switch>
    </StyledMain>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: You can see it work here https://codesandbox.io/s/34yl2r41k6  (I used `console.log` as it alerts too often)

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. What I eventually want to do is to put simple authentication to be able to access the route.

Comment: It works. It does the job what is intended here. Fire an alert or as you can see logging. You asked how can you do that and this answers your question.

Comment: Forgot to remove the component. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. But, again if you want to set up an authentication for your routes, just go to React Router documentation and look for it. There is a nice PrivateRoute example.